# How to catch twilio events in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, twilio, webhooks

I'm new in twilio and trying to understand how can i catch twilio's events in my backend (nodejs). For exemple each time i send a message, i want the console logs "Message sent" just for testing.

I read the twilio [webhook documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/webhooks) , however i can't really understand how to apply it in a nodejs environment.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: The gist of it is you make a webserver (express or whatever), and when something happens on twilio, they'll make an http call from their servers to the server url you specify, telling you that something happened.

Comment: Thanks. I created a server on node then now i don't know how  to specify to twilio that i ' ve a listening server. i Tried to enter my localhost address to the twilio api's callback url but it doesn't work and blocking my app (preventing my chanel to load). Sorry im noob.

Comment: Are you also sending messages from node, or from somewhere else? If you're sending them from node, then the answer by @marcos-placona should work just fine. Otherwise, by "localhost address", do you mean a private IP? You'll need to provide twilio with a publicly accessible address / port or they won't be able to send you messages.

Comment: I send messages only from client localhost. When i provide my localhost address in twilio, the channel no longer loading, so i think something are blocking the entire application. When i left the twilio's url callback blank, my channel can load again. I'm using the twilio getting start demo nodejs app. All i want is to catch in my backend (nodejs) every messages sent from the browser form. It seems simple to explain but i didn't get any accurate answer or infos in Twilio docs. For ex how translating this cURL command (-d 'Webhooks.OnMessageSent.Url=https://hooks.yoursite.com' \) in nodejs ?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here. I think you will find [this Twilio tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/server-notifications/node/express) great, as it will walk you through exactly what you're trying to do, and will show you how to add events to the console.

But the gist of what you want to do it is the following:

```
// Create a new REST API client to make authenticated requests against the
// twilio back end
var client = new twilio.RestClient('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID', 'TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN');

// Pass in parameters to the REST API using an object literal notation. The
// REST client will handle authentication and response serialzation for you.
client.sms.messages.create({
    to:'YOUR_NUMBER',
    from:'YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER',
    body:'Twilio message from Node.js'
}, function(error, message) {
    // The HTTP request to Twilio will run asynchronously. This callback
    // function will be called when a response is received from Twilio
    // The "error" variable will contain error information, if any.
    // If the request was successful, this value will be false
    if (!error) {
        // The second argument to the callback will contain the information
        // sent back by Twilio for the request. In this case, it is the
        // information about the text messsage you just sent:
        console.log('Success! The SID for this SMS message is:');
        console.log(message.sid);

        console.log('Message sent on:');
        console.log(message.dateCreated);
    } else {
        console.log('Oops! There was an error.');
    }
});
```

Full documentation for the Node library can be found [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node#more-documentation).

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure to understand. I don't want send messages from node but i want my nodejs backend to catch every messages sent from the browser/client. So that every time i send a message from my twilio browser, i can catch it in my backend and process to custom task (db storage, edit etc.) . Also, i'm not using twilio sms client but i'm using the twilio ip messaging.